# Determine the number of zeros using the Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm tasked with finding the zeros of $f(z)=z^3+1$ that lie inside the first quadrant using the Argument Principle, which I have simplified below:

$$N=\frac{1}{2\pi}[arg(f(z))]_C$$

where N represents the number of zeros and $[arg(f(z))]_C$ represents the change in the argument of $f(z)$ over C. The solution given by the book seems to be quite trivial, however, I'm having trouble piecing the process together. My analysis of the problem is below:

$$arg(f(z))=\phi \quad \tan(\phi)=\frac{Im(f(x,y))}{Re(f(x,y))} \quad arg(z)=\theta$$

We begin at the origin, $z=0 \rightarrow f(z) =1$, and move far down the real axis to a point $R$. At $R$ $z=x=R \rightarrow f(z)=R^3+1$ where our argument of $z$ has not changed, hence, neither has the argument of $f(z)$. However, we now move along a radial length to the point $iR$ on the imaginary axis. Along this radial curve, $\theta$ changes by $\pi/2$ since we have gone from having only a real component to now only having an imaginary component, and as a result, $\phi$ changes by $3\pi/2$. Lastly, we move from $iR$ back to $z=0$ along the imaginary axis. This is where I lose it and cannot deduce how $\theta$ changes. On this last leg we go from having a purely imaginary number to one that is zero, which I can't seem to make sense of, in terms of the argument of z. Care to provide any insight?

Comment: you know that with $\gamma$ the closed contour encircling your region, it is equivalent to compute $\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$, i.e. with the parametrization $\gamma(t), t \in [0,1]$, finding an antiderivative of $\frac{f'(\gamma(t))}{f(\gamma(t))} \gamma'(t) $.  and when $f'(z)/f(z)$ is a rational function, we can always apply partial fraction decomposition to $f'(z)/f(z)$ to find such an antiderivative.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I know. I just want to learn how to evaluate the question in this manner as this is how I will be tested.

Comment: the 2 are the same